# How to prove that a language is non-regular by using Pumping lemma with length?

Tags: pumping-lemma

I was given the following question:

Use the Pumping Lemma with length to prove that the following language is non-regular:
$L = \{b^na^{100}b^{2n}, \text{where n} = 1, 2, 3,...\}$

Use the prompts below to complete the proof
**Assume**

**Then there exists**

**We choose any word w =**

**Thus we can write w =**

**The according to the pumping lemma with length,**

**There is/are __ possible choice(s) for y**

**If y is pumped in each of the above case(s),**

Now, my answer, actually how far I came, is as follow:

**Assume** L is a regular language.
**Then there exists** an FA with, say k states that accepts L.
**We choose any word w =** $b^na^{100}b^2n$ in L.
**Thus we can write w =** $b^ka^{100}b^{2k}$
**The according to the pumping lemma with length,** w may be written as w = xyz such that |x| + |y| <= k and |y| > 0

Then I don't know further. I do know that y is 1 b or more. y is also at most k b's.

I would appreciate it if you will correct my mistakes and also finish the answer. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve filled in the first two blanks correctly, but after that you’ve gone a bit astray, I think because you’re not seeing how the contradiction is going to arise.

It’s true that you can start with any word in $L$, so $w$ **could** be $b^na^{100}b^{2n}$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and the pumping lemma would say something about other members of $L$, but if we want to make matters easy for ourselves, we’ll take $w=b^ka^{100}b^{2k}$. Then the pumping lemma says that we can write $w=xyz$, where $|y|\ge 1$, $|xy|\le k$, and $xy^nz\in L$ for each $n\ge 0$. So what can $y$ be? We know that $xy$ is the first $|xy|$ characters of $w$, and $|xy|\le k$, so $xy$ is contained in the first $k$ characters of $w$. And $w$ begins with $k$ $b$s, so $xy$ is a string of $b$s, say $xy=b^\ell$. What are the possible choices for $\ell$? It has to be at least $1$: $x$ can be the empty string, but we know that $|y|\ge 1$. And it can be at most $k$, since we know that $|xy|\le k$. Thus, $1\le\ell\le k$, and there are therefore $k$ possible choices for $y$, from $b^1$ through $b^k$.

Suppose that we pump $y$ in any of these cases: if we pump $y$ up to $y^2$, we change $y=b^\ell$ to $y^2=b^{2\ell}$, adding $\ell$ $b$s, and we get the word $b^{k+\ell}a^{100}b^{2k}$. And this is our contradiction: on the one hand the pumping lemma says that this must be in $L$, but on the other hand it clearly is **not** in $L$, since $2k\ne 2(k+\ell)$ (because $\ell\ne 0$). Thus, the initial assumption that $L$ is regular must have been false.

It is possible to use other initial words to get a contradiction, but this is the simplest.

Comment: I think your hypotheses is correct; I'm not seeing how the contradiction is going to arise simply because I don't understand how we can pump y. The language clearly states what the length of y can be so how can we pump the length of y above its limits. Do you understand my confusion? There are k possible choices for y but we are pumping y to twice that, then, yes, a contradiction will arise. It should arise within the definition of the language then it would make sense to me. Will you explain what I'm missing here.

Comment: @ClintTheron: You’re ignoring what the pumping lemma actually says: if $L$ is regular, $w\in L$, and $|w|\ge k$, then $w$ can always be decomposed into three substrings, $w=xyz$, with the following three properties: $|y|\ge 1$; $|xy|\le k$; and $xy^nz\in L$ for **every** $n\ge 0$. To understand why this is so, you have to understand the [proof of the pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Proof_of_the_pumping_lemma), but for now just accept that it **is** true. This means that if you have some language $L$ and find a word $w\in L$ such that ...

Comment: ... $|w|\ge k$, but any decomposition of $w$ as $xyz$ that satisfies the first two conditions ($|y|\ge 1$ and $|xy|\le k$) **fails** to satisfy the third, because there is at least one $n\ge 0$ such that $xy^nz$ is **not** in $L$, then your language could not have been regular in the first place. That’s what I did: I showed that if we start with $w=b^ka^{100}b^{2k}$, which is certainly in $L$, then any decomposition $w=xyz$ that satisfies the length conditions fails to satisfy the pumping condition, because $xy^2z$ provably is not in $L$. (In fact the **only** $n\ge 0$ for which ...

Comment: ... $xy^nz\in L$ is $n=1$.)

Comment: I don't get why you went back to n when you say, "Then the pumping lemma says that we can write...., and $xy^nz\in L$ for each $n\ge 0$." Why not k?

Comment: I think you also made a typo here, "And w begins with k b's, so xy is a string of a's". I think it should be a string of b's

Comment: @Clint: I don’t use $k$ as a variable there because we’re already using $k$ for a specific number, namely, the pumping length (the number of states in the finite automaton that accepts $L$). But yes, you did indeed catch a typo; I’ll fix it as soon as I post this comment.

Comment: I get now why you used n as variable. It's because you stating the properties of the pumping lemma. Thank you for the clarification. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Clint: You’re welcome.